# After upgrading Windows 10, WMDC stopped working

Tags: windows-10

My Windows 10 system has updated automatically today. After it updated, Windows Mobile Device Center disappeared. I tried to install it again, but installer shows this message: this operating system is not configured to install this application.

How can I solve it? Before updating, Windows Mobile Device Center worked without problems.

Regards
Jaime

Comment: Microsoft Community about Windows Mobile Device Center [link](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-win_upgrade/windows-mobile-device-center-compatibility-with/95c017d8-c243-48a1-bbdc-afb77255ca7f?auth=1)

Answer (score -1):

I used the below and it worked well. I clicked on {windows start} , chose windows system, right-clicked on command prompt and chose more, and chose to Run As Adminstartor. Then copied the 1st line from the link below and pressed enter (received succesful, then repeated for the 2nd line. Restarted my computer and all woked fine.
https://www.handheldgroup.com/support-rugged-computers/knowledgebase-KB/22996/